# htaccess redirect to alias folder not working

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, mod-alias

I have a website lets say `www.myweb.com`
I have a folder for my forum question named ascommunity. I have created an alias to the folder to load `index.php`. Which means `www.myweb.com/community` will `index.php` which will load all questions.

I have another php page question.php which will load the detail of the question. So If I will load `www.myweb.com/community/question.php?ques=my` new question, it will gve me the detail of the question. But I want url to be like `www.myweb.com/community/question/mynewquestion`.

I have written htaccess to achieve that but it's not working for alias folder. Here is what I am using in my htaccess which is in community folder.

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^question/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ question.php?ques=$1
```

When I load `www.myweb.com/community/question/mynewquestion` it says 404 not found error.

But If I will load `www.myweb.com/community/question.php?ques=mynewquestion` It works fine as there is no htacces rule applied.

I got stucked here.

Comment: Your `RewriteBase` is wrong. It should be `RewriteBase /comunity/`, otherwise you will request `/question-php` which does not exist. Alternatively you can add the community folder to the rule target.

Comment: I tried with that also but didn't work. I am doing like this

Comment: And "didn't work" means what _exactly_? What does it rewrite to? What does your log file say?

Comment: I am doing like this <a href = "question/mynewquestion"> from index.php. The htaccess works fine if its like community.myweb.com/question/mynewquestion. But I want www.myweb.com/community/question/mynewquestion

Comment: That is not an answer to the question I asked. What is the request getting rewritten to? What does your log file say?

Comment: The diiference is like that www.myweb.com/comunity is pointing to /var/www/html/community through alias.

Comment: Ok, still not answering questions, I am out. Good luck!

Comment: It says 404. Its not redirecting anywhere. Its on the same url www.myweb.com/community/question/mynewquestion. The diiference is like that www.myweb.com/comunity is pointing to /var/www/html/community through alias. but community.myweb.com is apache config pointed to /var/www/html/community.

Comment: You do know what a log file is, do you?

Comment: Thanks  #arkascha for helping whatever you understood. I think you got what I want to achieve.

Comment: I _think_ I do, yes. But you will have to provide the information required to answer that. If you do not, then how should _we_ help? May I ask _why_ you don't answer? Maybe I miss a point here.